# How to validate without empty other filled fields Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi there I have this fields:

```
  <form role="form" class="form margin-bottom-0" action="{{ url('/test') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {{ csrf_field() }}   
    <div class="box box-widget widget-use padding-40 padding-top-0 box-shadow-none">    

            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <input class="form-control" name="name"  id="regular2" type="text" value="@if($account){{$account['name']}} @endif" >
                        <label for="regular2" >@lang('payment.full_name')</label>

                        @if ($errors->has('name'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label {{ $errors->has('address') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <input class="form-control" name="address"  id="regular2" type="text" value="@if($account){{$account['address']}}@endif" >
                        <label for="regular2">@lang('payment.address')</label>
                        @if ($errors->has('address'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn save-lang savecard">@lang('buttons.save_changes')</button>
    </form>
```

and when I submit it shows me the validation just fine 
but when I fill one field and I submit the field that I put text on it empties, how can I make the text to stay..?

Comment: Can you add your validation code/rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on every inputs you have:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name"  id="regular2" type="text" value="{{ old('name') }}" >
```

Just use `old()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old method in your template referring the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input)
If you use `$this->validate(/*your rules*/)` in your controller, it will send the errors and the old input.
Then your can use for exemple :
`<input class="form-control" name="name"  id="regular2" type="text" value="{{ old('name') }}" >` To make the text stay.

Hopes it helps you.